# How can I install new charts on GKE with helm3 remotely?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I get this error with helm3, why?

```
$ gcloud config list
[core]
account = xxxxx@xxxxx
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = project1-xxxxx

Your active configuration is: [xconfig]

$ kubectl get nodes --cluster gke_project1-xxxxx-central1-c_cluster-1
NAME                                       STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-xxxxx-xxxxx   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.19.9-gke.1400
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-xxxxx-xxxxx   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.19.9-gke.1400
gke-cluster-1-default-pool-xxxxx-xxxxx   Ready    <none>   159m   v1.19.9-gke.1400

$ helm3 install -f values.yaml confluent confluentinc/cp-helm-charts
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/AppProtection/libAppProtection.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable
```

Comment: Can you check the permissions of kube-config file

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Helm problem, or even necessarily a programming-related issue.  [This answer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) suggests a specific piece of software that could be conflicting, maybe?

Comment: @SravanKumar I have not used any kube-config file. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Could this [guide](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts#installation), from official repository, help you for installing confluentinc?

```
helm repo add confluentinc https://confluentinc.github.io/cp-helm-charts/   #(1)
helm repo update    #(2)
helm install confluentinc/cp-helm-charts --name my-confluent --version 0.6.0
```

Check the [kubeconfig file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/#merging-kubeconfig-files) with `$ kubectl config view`

Comment: I get the same error: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable